# calculate the number of characters in a string recursively

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the number of characters in a string by using recursive method. here is my code in java

```
public class MainClass {

    public int length(String str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {   
            return length(str.substring(1))+1; // in eclipse it says : at MainClass.length(MainClass.java:12)
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        MainClass m = new MainClass();
        System.out.println(m.length("ali"));    
    }
}
```

This line does not work : `return length(str.substring(1))+1;`
How can I correct the code?
Thanks

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `str` is a reference to an empty string? (Note that the error message should show the exception involved, not just "at MainClass.length"... the exception is really important, and I'd expect the message to be useful to you...)

Comment: When you reach the end of your string in your recursion, you have a String with length 0, it's not ``null``. Your check ``str==null`` makes no sense.

Comment: `return String.length()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the case when your `String` argument is an empty string, include that in your check:

```
if (str == null || str.length()==0) {
  return 0;
} else {   
[...]
```

Please note that the Exception that you get contains valuable information about what's going wrong, in this case it's probably a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you call `substring(1)` on an empty `String` object.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
public int length(String str) {

if (str==null||str.isEmpty()) {
   return 0;
 }else {  
 return length(str.substring(1))+1
}
```